# Team Foundation Server Administration Console throws error message "Servicing"; tfsjobagent.exe has an error during job execution

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Randomly, the TFS 2010 Server stopped working.  When I go to the console to see what is going on, I get a simple "Servicing" error message.  When I click okay, none of the Team Project Collections actually show up.

When I go to the Event Viewer and look at the log, I see the following message:

> Application Domain: TfsJobAgent.exe
> Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
> Service Host:
> Process Details:
> Process Name: TFSJobAgent
> Process Id: 2680
> Thread Id: 3304
> Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Detailed Message: There was an error during job agent execution. The operation will be retried. Similar errors in the next five minutes may not be logged.
> Exception Message: Servicing (type HostShutdownException)
>
> Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationServiceHost.ThrowIfShutdown()
> at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationServiceHost.CreateSystemContext()
> at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobApplication.SetupInternal()
> at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobServiceUtil.RetryOperationsUntilSuccessful(RetryOperations operations)

I've done some googling and some people have suggested this is a sql server login issue.  There have been NO CONFIGURATION CHANGES of any kind to the database or the TFS application layer.

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems like connection issue for me. There is one retry operation
   in the stack trace.
2. You don't have TFS2010 SP1 installed apparently (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0). Please try to install [TFS2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20506).